# VB reading objExcel limited to 16384 rows

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a vb script that loops through an excel file. 
when I get to and past row 16384, I get a blank back and not the cell value

I've tried forcing the type to long, but that does not help

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(xlsfile)
set objsheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
i=16400 
UserID= objsheet.Cells(i,2).value
```

I've also just tried UserID= objsheet.Cells(16388,2).value

I would hope to get the cell value, but am getting blank whenever the index goes over

Comment: Did you declare all your variables? Is `i` a `Long`?

Comment: Do you in fact have data past that row on that worksheet?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. 
1. 16400 is not a long value. I tried type casting it in the call.
2. :) that would be funny. yes, I have data through row 28,000
It seems like other people are able to read until at least 65K rows. 
I wonder if it is some windows library that I need to update? Any ideas ??

Comment: Rowlimit was 16.384 in Excel 95(!) (not sure that version even supported automation), it was higher in all later versions. Check the version just for fun?

Comment: I'm on windows 10 using Office 365 - 64 bit.

Comment: Could it be that the file you are reading was saved for the 95 version?